# Rails / Zeus: "MiniTest v5.0.8 is out of date" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, bundler, minitest, zeus

I recently set up Zeus and Minitest for testing a Rails app.

However, I got the following error:

```
leo% zeus test
/Users/leo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@backscratchers/gems/turn-0.9.6/lib/turn/minitest.rb:23:in `<top (required)>': MiniTest v5.0.8 is out of date.
`gem install minitest` and add `gem 'minitest' to you test helper. (RuntimeError)
  from /Users/leo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@backscratchers/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
  from /Users/leo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@backscratchers/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
  ... etc ...
```

The line mentioned in the Turn gem is:

```
# set MiniTest's runner to Turn::MiniRunner instance
if MiniTest::Unit.respond_to?(:runner=)
  MiniTest::Unit.runner = Turn::MiniRunner.new
else
  raise "MiniTest v#{MiniTest::Unit::VERSION} is out of date.\n" \
        "`gem install minitest` and add `gem 'minitest' to you test helper."
  #MiniTest::Unit = Turn::MiniRunner
end
```

So the 'out of date' is a bit misleading perhaps. What it really means is the API is not what’s expected, right?

I removed `gem 'turn'` from my Gemfile, run `bundle install`, and restart Zeus.

Now I get:

```
/Users/leo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:328:in `autorun': uninitialized class variable @@installed_at_exit in Test::Unit::Runner (NameError)
  from /Users/leo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:640:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/leo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@backscratchers/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
  from /Users/leo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@backscratchers/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
  from /Users/leo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@backscratchers/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `l
... etc ...
```

What’s going on here? Do I somehow have the wrong version of Minitest? Why has Bundler not been able to figure out the dependency chain, I thought that was the point.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Well the immediate solution appears to be downgrading Minitest:

`gem 'minitest', '~> 4'`

However, this then seems to cause knock-on issues when running particular test, as I am now getting `uninitialized constant MiniTest::Test` errors when actually running the tests.

***Update:***

It seems older versions of MiniTest used a different module/class hierarchy, so `Minitest::Test` must become `MiniTest::Unit::TestCase`.

Note the capitalization of Minitest > MiniTest.

To see what Classes are available to your MiniTest/Minitest, you can use:

```
MiniTest.constants.select {|c| Class === MiniTest.const_get(c)}
```